# Adverse Effects of Liquid Diet

Tags: diet, dentistry, side-effects, stomach

If I eat liquid food for 19/21 meals each week, will there be any adverse side effects? Assume that the liquid meals have the exact same nutritional content as a regular solid meal.

Comment: I found one side effect. My back teeth become sticky at the end of the day. If I chew something, then the stickiness goes away.